# What is a native bridge

Tags: design-patterns, native, definition

In various development environments, a layer around native functionality is referred to as a "native bridge" (For example: [RoboVM](http://docs.robovm.com/advanced-topics/bro.html)).

Why is this called a bridge? and does it have any relation to the [Bridge design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) ?

Comment: i guess what you are referring to is a proxy pattern..it's not bridge

Answer (score 2):

I believe in this case the term "bridge" means, essentially, to allow access to something that is otherwise inaccessible. You cannot normally call native C functions from Java directly - you need to use a bridge (which provides a Java API as a means to call C functions, or which allows Java methods to be implemented in C).

I don't think this is the same as the bridge design pattern, which, as it says on the wikipedia page, is to *decouple an abstraction from its implementation so that the two can vary independently*. In a Java-to-native bridge there is no particular abstraction or implementation - so this is not a design pattern.